# control the camera flash iPhone

Tags: iphone, camera

I was wondering if it is possible to set up an app that will turn on and off the flash of the camera in sequences like a Morse code or an SOS signal or something similar. I have done a little  research but i didnt find anything conclusive.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Given that there are apps in the App Store that do this, yes, it's entirely possible.

Comment: Thx for letting me know that is possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to turn on the flashlight:

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error: nil];
[session addInput:input];

AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
[session addOutput:output];

[session beginConfiguration];
[device lockForConfiguration:nil];

[device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];

[device unlockForConfiguration];
[session commitConfiguration];

[session startRunning];
```

And to turn it off again:

```
[session stopRunning];
```

You'll need to turn the flashlight on and off with the timings you want using something like `NSTimer`.